# Bash - Grabbing value of a command (string) and seeing if it matches another string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Attempting to grab the output displayed by `cyberghostvpn --status` in the terminal, which is either `No VPN connections found.` or `VPN connection found.`

I've tried `| grep -x "No VPN connections found."` on $VPN_status and received errors. Can't even remember everything I've tried for the past couple hours. Feel like this is a simple solution but I'm just missing it. Here is the code ($index is a random selection from an array not listed in this excerpt):

```
VPN_status="$(cyberghostvpn --status)"
echo $VPN_status
if [[ $? == "No VPN connetions found." ]]; then
    echo "Connecting to VPN."
    cyberghostvpn --country-code $index --server-type traffic --openvpn --connect
else
    echo "You are connected to the VPN already."
fi
```

This returns:

```
No VPN connections found.
You are connected to the VPN already.
```

EDIT - Working perfectly now. Here is the updated code -

```
array=("AD" "AE" "AL" "AM" "AR" "AT" "BA" "BD" "BE" "BG" "BR" "BS" "BY" "CH" "CL" "CN" "CO" "CR" "CY" "CZ" "DE" "DK" "DZ" "EE" "EG" "ES" "FI" "FR" "GB" "GE" "GL" "GR" "HK" "HR" "HU" "ID" "IE" "IL" "IM" "IN" "IR" "IS" "IT" "JP" "KE" "KH" "KR" "KZ" "LI" "LK" "LT" "LU" "LV" "MA" "MC" "MD" "ME" "MK" "MN" "MO" "MT" "MX" "MY" "NG" "NL" "NO" "NZ" "PA" "PH" "PK" "PL" "PT" "QA" "RO" "RS" "RU" "SA" "SE" "SG" "SI" "SK" "TH" "TR" "TW" "UA" "US" "VE" "VN" "ZA")
size="${#array[@]}"
index=$[ $RANDOM % $size ]
Country=${array[$index]}
VPN_status="$(cyberghostvpn --status)"
VPN_connect="$(cyberghostvpn --openvpn --traffic --country-code $Country --connect)"
echo $VPN_status
if [[ $VPN_status == "No VPN connections found." ]]; then
    echo "Connecting to VPN."
    $VPN_connect
    echo "New country is $Country"
elif [[ $VPN_status == "VPN connection found." ]]; then
    echo "Changing country..."
    echo "New country is $Country"
else
    echo "This shouldn't have happened..."
fi
```

ty all

Comment: Just a random thought ... does `cyberghostvpn --status` also emit a status, e.g. `0` for connected, `1` for disconnected?  What does `echo $?` give you in either case straight  after running the status check?

Comment: @tink it might. Unsure. Just stepped out, when I get back in few mins I’ll try echo $? To see what it says after entering status command through terminal, Ty

Comment: echo $? returns 0 for disconnected

Comment: And for connected?

Comment: @Grim : `$?` will always be some integer. `[[ $? == "No VPN connetions found." ]]` will always be false, because no integer can be equal to this string.

Comment: @tink I just connected to a specific country using a country code as the command arguments request, and it says 127. Then I disconnected and tried another country code and it connected successfully....but echo $? returned 0.....not quite sure why that would be...

Comment: @user1934428 I changed it to `echo $VPN_status
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then` instead and it seemed to work. However, when I enter flags for the command which is required to run the command, I get `No VPN connections found.
Connecting to VPN.
./script.sh: line 34: Prepare: command not found`

Whatever line where I call command and its flags to be entered into the terminal, it says command not found, I tried making it a variable instead of just doing `"$(cyberghostvpn --openvpn --traffic --country-code $index --connect)"`
below `echo "Connecting to VPN."`

but it still gives me an error

Comment: You would have to add this information (properly formatted) to your question. You can edit your question, and at the bottom you write "Additional Information", and add the new code which you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking against the return code (a number) not the text.

This will probably work:

```
VPN_status="$(cyberghostvpn --status)"
echo $VPN_status
if [[ $VPN_status == "No VPN connetions found." ]]; then
    echo "Connecting to VPN."
    cyberghostvpn --country-code $index --server-type traffic --openvpn --connect
else
    echo "You are connected to the VPN already."
fi
```

Comment: Could swear I tried that before but I don’t remember now. Just stepped out will let you know in a few mins if it works. Ty

Comment: No, unfortunately changing $? for $VPN_status returns the same result. Ty, tho. Following what @tink suggested for echoing cyberghostvpn --status shows 0 when disconnected. So likely it shows 1 when connected, guess there would be a way to create an if statement that tests for 1 or 0 as true or false?

Comment: It works for me with the string when I mock it. You can try to echo the return code. `echo $?` Then `if [[ $? == 0 ]]` should work if they're different.

Comment: Yes just tested echo `echo $VPN_status
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then`

and it seems to work now, ty :) one more problem now which is it seems to not be successfully entering `cyberghostvpn --country-code $index --server-type traffic --openvpn --connect`

Comment: Apparently that is the error code from `$?`, so it still returns 0 connected or disconnected.

Comment: Think I might have figured out the "command not found" problem. Using `/bin/bash -x` after the shebang in my script and logging that debug output to a temp log, I see this `++ cyberghostvpn --openvpn --traffic --country-code 17 --connect`

country-code should be a two letter argument, not a number. Hopefully changing my array will solve this

Comment: Figured it out. Works great now and connects to random country. Selected random string in array by using 
`size="${#array[@]}"

index=$[ $RANDOM % $size ]

Country=${array[$index]}
VPN_status="$(cyberghostvpn --status)"
VPN_connect="$(cyberghostvpn --openvpn --traffic --country-code $Country --connect)"`

Answer (score 1):

Under the not unreasonable assumption, that `cyberghostvpn --status` sets exit code zero if the connection is up, you could simply write

```
if cyberghostvpn --status
then
  echo You are connected
else
  echo Trying to connect 
  ....
fi
```

Comment: When I run this connected to the VPN, it says
`VPN connection found.
You are connected.`
Which is great, but disconnected it says
`No VPN connections found.
You are connected.`

Ty for this though, this `--status` flag returns unexpected integers when I use `echo $?` after running it. One connection to a specific country it returned 127. on another, it was 0, but it was connected

Comment: Apparently that is the error code from `$?`, so it still returns 0 connected or disconnected